# Ansible conditional based on return data

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

I run simple script to add new user when this user not exists.

```
---
- name: gather facts
  hosts: r5
  #gather_facts: yes

  tasks:

  - name:
    ios_command:
      commands: sh run | s user
    register: username_contents

  - name: check if user exists, if not add user
    ios_config:
      lines: username test privilege 15 secret test
    when: ('test') not in username_contents.stdout
```

Ansible adds this user as expected but when I run this test again despite having 'test' in variable it still adds it.

```
TASK [ios_command] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [r5]

TASK [check if user exists, if not add user] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [r5]

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
r5                         : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Output for 'sh run | s user':

```
ok: [r5] => {
    "username_contents.stdout": [
        "username cisco privilege 15 secret 5 $1$rIId$7X8jj.iJiU3s4AKladf2dE/\nusername test privilege 15 secret 5 $1$aLpg$UnHXbCENzJxBonbdWshXA."
    ]
}
```

Comment: `in` used with the list `stdout_lines` will succeed if one of the lines is exactly `'test'`. You want to use instead the string `stdout` (i.e. concatenation of all lines). The test will then succeed if `'test'` is found somewhere in the the string.

Comment: I tried both ways, but no luck

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/25e3dfc2a660f984f05712ec2e912ccc

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

> The network modules, because they can contain the output from multiple
>   commands, structure the stdout as a list of strings.
>
> As such, if you are running a single command, then you would do:
>
> when: usr in username_contents['stdout'][0]

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69316#issuecomment-623659676